# Custom Gradle Plugin executed only once in Multiproject build

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have written a gradle plugin in Java, which I want to use in a multiproject gradle setup. The task which comes with the plugin is only executed once and I don't understand why.

The structure of the project looks like this:

```
Root project
     |- settings.gradle
     |- build.gradle
     |- project1
     |     |- build.gradle
     |- project2
     |     |- build.gradle
     |- project3
     |     |- build.gradle
     ...
```

The root build.gradle looks like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }

    maven{
        url = "https://my-personal-nexus.de/content/repositories/release/"
    }
    ....
    dependencies {
       ....
       classpath "de.mystuff:myCustomPlugin:1.0.0"
    }
  }
}
subprojects {
   apply plugin: "myCustomPlugin"
   ....
}
```

The plugin "myCustomPlugin" provides a Task called myTask. Since the Plugin is applied in die subprojects part of the build.gradle, I assumed that when I call:

```
./gradlew myTask
```

the task would be executed for project1, project2, project3.

In reality the task only executes in project1 and not in project2 or project3. If I call

```
./gradlew -p "project2" myTask
```

the task is executed in project 2 just fine.
Any hints on why the task is not executed for every subproject?

When I call

```
 ./gradlew tasks --all
```

The result shows the task for every subproject.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The Plugin code of the Task:

```
public class MyGeneratorTask extends DefaultTask {

@TaskAction
public void genMyCode() throws Exception {
        MyGeneratorExtension extension = getProject().getExtensions().getByType(MyGeneratorExtension.class);
        MyGeneratorConfig.setPath(extension.getPath());
        MyGeneratorConfig.setGendir(extension.getGendir());
        MyCodeGeneratorApplication.generateMyClasses();
    }
}
```

And the plugin definition itself:

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    static final String GEN_TASK_CONFIG = "myConfig";
    static final String GEN_TASK_NAME = "myTask";

    @Override
    public void apply(Project target) {
        target.getExtensions().add(GEN_TASK_CONFIG, MyGeneratorExtension.class);
        target.getTasks().create(GEN_TASK_NAME, MyGeneratorTask.class);
    }
}
```

And the code of the extension:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class MyGeneratorExtension {

   private String path;
   private String gendir;

}
```

Comment: You assumed right: when calling `./gradlew myTask` Gradle should call your task on all sub-projects. Can you share the part of your plugin script where you create the `myTask` task and where you add this task to the projects ?

Comment: I added the code, thank you

Comment: The way you create extension and the task on subprojects is correct, I don't see anything wrong here.. when you execute `./gradlew myTask`, what is the output log of Gradle?  do you see that `myTask` is "SKIPPED" for other subprojects (except "project1") or no log at all for the other sub-projects ?

Comment: The output is: BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s 1 actionable task: 1 executed. I also looked at the executed tasks with --console=plain. The tasks are not SKIPPED but never called. I am clueless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

It Seems that gradle does not like it when you call a static Method in a Task.
After I switched to class-initialization it worked.

Thanks @M.Ricciuti

Comment: Strange thing is that I have tried your solution (copy-pasted your code with a simple implementation of `MyGeneratorConfig` and `MyCodeGeneratorApplication` using static fields/methods as you did) and it worked fine for me...

Comment: That is indeed strange.